# What are finite homotopy types?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Starting from an ordinary 1-categorical point of view, there are various obvious candidate definitions for ‘finite homotopy type’:

- The homotopy type of a simplicial set that has only finitely many non-degenerate simplices.
- The homotopy type of a CW complex that has only finitely many cells.
- The homotopy type of the nerve of a finitely-presentable category.

Homotopy type theory affords another candidate:

- A higher inductive type that admits a finite presentation in some syntactic sense.

**Question.** Do these notions coincide? To what extent is each one the ‘right’ notion of finiteness for homotopy types? For instance, are these precisely the homotopy types $X$ such that the representable functor $\mathrm{Hom}(X, -) : \infty \mathbf{Grpd} \to \infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ preserves (homotopy) filtered colimits?

Answer (score 16):

I believe the first *two* notions coincide, but they definitely don't coincide with the third: as was pointed out in a deleted answer, the nerve of any finite group is a (3) but certainly not a (1) or (2) in general.  I think most would agree that (3) is not a good notion of finiteness.

As for HITs, any (1) or (2) can be presented by a HIT of a very simple form: all constructors take zero arguments and the source and target of each constructor is an $\infty$-groupoid expression in the previous ones.  I haven't written out a proof, but the converse should also be true.

I don't think I would presume to say whether these, or their retracts, are the "right" notion of finiteness.  Perhaps there is no unique "right" notion.

Comment: The non-existence of a unique right notion would be unsurprising, given the plethora of notions in e.g. constructive mathematics and even choiceless classical mathematics!

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your last question is no. The compact (small) objects in $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ are the *retracts* of finite CW complexes. See, e.g. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category
(also google "Wall's finiteness obstruction").

<del>As to whether the first three notions coincide, I would guess yes, but I haven't thought about it much.</del>

EDIT: The third class is strictly larger, as was just pointed out in Mike Shulman's answer. Theorem 2C.5 in Hatcher states that any finite CW complex has the homotopy type of a finite simplicial complex. This shows that the first two notions coincide, and are contained in the third notion (take the poset corresponding to a finite simplicial complex).

Comment: Ha! I added that bit to the nlab earlier today!

Comment: The fact that the compact objects in $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ are the retracts of finite CW complexes also appears in Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory* Remark 5.4.1.6. Note, however, that the finite CW complexes still generate $\infty \mathbf{Grpd}$ under filtered colimits.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible definition of "finite homotopy type" but not from a categorical point of view is suggested by the paper

SPACES WITH  FINITELY  MANY  NON-TRIVIAL   HOMOTOPY GROUPS  ALL  OF  WHICH  ARE  FINITE , GRAHAM ELLIS , Topdogy   Vol.  36, No.  2,  pp.  501-504,    1997

This shows that for such a connected CW-space, its homotopy type  may be represented by a simplicial  group  such  that  its  group  of $ n$ -simplices  is  finite  for  each 
$n \geqslant  0$.

Comment: I've heard those spaces called "π-finite".