# Is the infinity-groupoid of a finite CW complex finitely-presented?

Tags: homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, cw-complexes, infinity-topos-theory, homotopy-type-theory

An infinity-groupoid is finitely-presented when it is equivalent to the free infinity-groupoid on a finite family of generators, possibly of different dimensions.

**Is the infinity-groupoid of a finite CW complex finitely-presented?**

It seems to me this question is relevant for homotopy type theory, in which topological spaces are constructed as higher inductive types from a finite family of generators.

Comment: Thanks to Urs Schreiber explaining some things to me today which led me to consider this question.

Comment: See [Mike Shulman's answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/136897/11640).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CW structure is precisely a presentation of an $\infty$-groupoid, and so "finite CW complex" means precisely "finitely presented $\infty$-groupoid."

Comment: thanks. This makes sense to me, although I do not quite see why it is a trivial statement... I will think further.

Comment: What model of an oo-groupoid are you using? Clearly n-cells are generators in dimension n, but how does one interpret the attaching maps? Split in half and let the halves be source and target in a globular oo-groupoid?

Comment: This is a model-independent statement. Of course it depends on what the OP means by "free $\infty$-groupoid on a finite family of generators," but I think this is a reasonable interpretation. Think first about how one presents a group $G$ in terms of generators and relations. Topologically generators correspond to $1$-cells and relations correspond to $2$-cells. So in fact a presentation describes a CW complex of dimension $2$ (the presentation complex). This is the beginning of a presentation / CW description of $BG$, and one now needs to add $3$-cells, etc. These are simultaneously...

Comment: ...new "generators" in the sense that they may (before we kill them again) give rise to higher homotopy and new "relations" in the sense that they themselves kill homotopy.

Comment: Another way to say it: a presentation of a group is a description of that group as the cokernel of a map between free groups. Keeping in mind the analogy to free resolutions of modules, we might say more generally that "presentation" means "description of an object as a colimit of free objects." And a CW decomposition is precisely a description of a space as an iterated homotopy pushout of spheres (which themselves are iterated homotopy pushouts of points).

Comment: It appears to me that the OP is thinking in terms of homotopy type theory, so here "finitely presented ∞-groupoid" should be "higher inductive type with finitely many constructors".